# Documentation example gives different answer in Mathematica 11.3

Tags: parallelization, documentation

I have been looking at the very first example on this [page](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ParallelTools/tutorial/ParallelEvaluation.html) of the documentation in Mathematica 11.3 (default installation options) and I get a different result:

```
LaunchKernels[2]; 
Kernels[]; 
mykernel = First[Kernels[]]; 
a = 2; 
ParallelEvaluate[a === 2, mykernel]
```

Which outputs

```
True
```

whereas in the documentation it gives False.

Have there been any changes to parallel computing in Mathematica recently?

Comment: I updated some inaccurate comments in my answer. I think this is essentially a duplicate of the above  QA (in the sense that both questions have the same answer). Please do report the documentation inconsistency to Wolfram. You can do that with the feedback link at the end of each *online* doc page.

Comment: Will do today evening

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, this has been deliberately changed in version 10.4. `ParallelEvaluate` will now automatically distribute definitions, just like the other parallel functions do.

Personally, I find this change counterproductive.  I often used `ParallelEvaluate` to examine the state of subkernels, and not having automatic magic working in the background made this easier.

But luckily, there is an easy workaround through the [`DistributedContexts`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DistributedContexts.html) option. To get back the old behaviour, use

```
ParallelEvaluate[..., DistributedContexts -> None]
```